# How does @Value annotation inject values when passed in parameters of a method?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am new to Spring, I was working with @Value annotation and found out that it can be applied to **fields or constructor/method parameters**, but as I was trying to inject value using parameters it was not injecting the value for my parameters and I was getting values as **null**
.

**I have used @Value in the parameter of the method below**

```
public void setName(@Value("Adventure of War") String name) {
        System.out.println("Setting Company Name");
        this.name = name;
}
```

**Complete code(Company.java)**

```
package gd.rf.anuragsaini.stereotype;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Company {
    String name;
    String motive;

    public void setName(@Value("Adventure of War") String name) {
        System.out.println("Setting Company Name");
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setMotive(@Value("A place for War") String motive) {
        System.out.println("Setting Company Motive");
        this.motive = motive;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", motive='" + motive + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Main File(App.java)**

```
package gd.rf.anuragsaini.stereotype;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext IOC = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
        Company c1 = IOC.getBean("company", Company.class);
        System.out.println(c1);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Company{name='null', motive='null'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that the setters will not be invoked.When constructing the bean of type Company, the frameWork use by default the default constructor of the class Company.

**So you should use** `@Autowired` **for the setters to garantee that the setters will be invoked by the frameWork when constructing those beans** :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Company {
    String name;
    String motive;

    @Autowired
    public void setName(@Value("Adventure of War") String name) {
        System.out.println("Setting Company Name");
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMotive(@Value("A place for War") String motive) {
        System.out.println("Setting Company Motive");
        this.motive = motive;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", motive='" + motive + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

---

Output :

```
Company{name='Adventure of War', motive='A place for War'}
```